# Getting the last modification date of a file in Inno Setup Pascal Script

Tags: datetime, scripting, inno-setup, pascal, datestamp

I need to choose the most recently modified file in my installation script.  It seems the Pascal scripting language has no `GetFileDateTime` or similar, so I am resorting to:

```pascal
function FileDateTime (FileID : string) : double ;

var
   FindRec        : TFindRec;

begin
    Result := 0.00 ;
    if (FindFirst (FileID, FindRec)) then
        begin
        try
            Result := FindRec.LastWriteTime ;  { gives type mismatch, naturally }
        finally
            FindClose (FindRec) ;
        end ;
    end ;
end ;
```

but I can't find any documentation on the format of `LastWriteTime`.  Ideally I want the datetime returned in a format that will make it relatively easy to display it, as I will need to write the equivalent of Delphi's `FormatDateTime` as well.  Inno Pascal has `GetDateTimeString` but this only formats the current datetime, not an arbitrary datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on the `TFindRec` record in InnoSetup is [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_findfirst.htm). It is very sparse, but I am almost confident that it has the exact same format as the corresponding structure in the Windows API.

Indeed, InnoSetup's `FindFirst` function most likely corresponds to [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx) of the Windows API. Thus, the `TFindRec` record corresponds to the [`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365740%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure so that a `TFileTime` record corresponds to a [`FILETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure.

Comment: so what is the answer, as there is type miss match? how did you match the types?

Comment: code could be found at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749954/get-a-files-last-updated-time-using-pascal-innosetup/1065605#1065605

Answer (score 0):

```
type  
SYSTEMTIME = record 
  Year:         WORD; 
  Month:        WORD; 
  DayOfWeek:    WORD; 
  Day:          WORD; 
  Hour:         WORD; 
  Minute:       WORD; 
  Second:       WORD; 
  Milliseconds: WORD; 
end; 


function FileTimeToSystemTime(
FileTime:        TFileTime; 
var SystemTime:  SYSTEMTIME
): Boolean; 
external 'FileTimeToSystemTime@kernel32.dll stdcall'; 


function GetModifiedFileDate(strFile : String) : Boolean;
var 
   FindRec: TFindRec;  
   SystemInfo: SYSTEMTIME;  
begin 
   if FindFirst(strFile, FindRec) then begin
      FileTimeToSystemTime( FindRec.LastWriteTime, SystemInfo);  
end;  
MsgBox(format('%4.4d-%2.2d-%2.2d', [SystemInfo.Year, SystemInfo.Month, SystemInfo.Day]), mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Nice. But can you modify the `GetModifiedFileDate` so that its signature makes some sense? It's a function returning `Boolean`, but it does not return anything.