Inno Setup replaced files not taking on the new date/time
When installing a file, Inno Setup doesn't seem to take on the new date/time of the file being replaced. The log indicates the file was replaced, but the date/time is the same as the old date/time. Shouldn't the replaced file have the same date/time of the new file?  In essence, I don't know if the file has actually been replaced.
Logging indicates the file was replaced.  But, I'm still seeing the old date/time on the replaced file.
InnoSetupTest.iss
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "InnoSetupTest"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "InnoSetupTest"
#define MyAppExeName "InnoSetupTest.exe"
#define MyAppDir "AutoTrader"

[Setup]
;SignTool=mystandard
;SignedUninstaller=yes
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
AppId={{BA5DEA98-E5E3-4DC4-BB72-94005FE539FC}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={autopf}\{#MyAppPublisher}\{#MyAppName}
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\{#MyAppExeName}
OutputBaseFilename={#MyAppName}_installer
OutputDir=.
;Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
PrivilegesRequired=admin
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern
SetupLogging=yes

[Files]
Source: "InnoSetupTest.exe"; DestDir: "{sd}\{#MyAppDir}"; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files
; if not ShellExec('Print', '{app}\STE_license.txt', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ResultCode) then

InnoSetup Log File:
2024-06-20 05:28:07.377   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC-05:00)
2024-06-20 05:28:07.378   Setup version: Inno Setup version 6.2.0
2024-06-20 05:28:07.378   Original Setup EXE: C:\InnoSetupTest\InnoSetupTest_installer.exe
2024-06-20 05:28:07.378   Setup command line: /SL5="$660D80,1288873,831488,C:\InnoSetupTest\InnoSetupTest_installer.exe" /SPAWNWND=$680EDC /NOTIFYWND=$190D7A 
2024-06-20 05:28:07.378   Compatibility mode: Yes (Installer)
2024-06-20 05:28:07.378   Windows version: 10.0.22000  (NT platform: Yes)
2024-06-20 05:28:07.378   64-bit Windows: Yes
2024-06-20 05:28:07.378   Processor architecture: x64
2024-06-20 05:28:07.378   User privileges: Administrative
2024-06-20 05:28:07.380   Administrative install mode: Yes
2024-06-20 05:28:07.380   Install mode root key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
2024-06-20 05:28:07.380   64-bit install mode: Yes
2024-06-20 05:28:07.388   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\email\AppData\Local\Temp\is-JPNJU.tmp
2024-06-20 05:28:12.271   Found 1 files to register with RestartManager.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.271   Calling RestartManager's RmGetList.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.279   RmGetList finished successfully.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.279   RestartManager found no applications using one of our files.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.296   Starting the installation process.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.299   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files\InnoSetupTest\InnoSetupTest
2024-06-20 05:28:12.299   Will append to existing uninstall log: C:\Program Files\InnoSetupTest\InnoSetupTest\unins000.dat
2024-06-20 05:28:12.302   -- File entry --
2024-06-20 05:28:12.302   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\InnoSetupTest\InnoSetupTest\unins000.exe
2024-06-20 05:28:12.302   Non-default bitness: 32-bit
2024-06-20 05:28:12.305   Time stamp of our file: 2024-06-20 05:28:07.235
2024-06-20 05:28:12.305   Dest file exists.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.305   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-06-20 05:25:17.340
2024-06-20 05:28:12.305   Version of our file: 51.1052.0.0
2024-06-20 05:28:12.306   Version of existing file: 51.1052.0.0
2024-06-20 05:28:12.306   Installing the file.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.312   Leaving temporary file in place for now.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.313   -- File entry --
2024-06-20 05:28:12.313   Dest filename: C:\AutoTrader\InnoSetupTest.exe
2024-06-20 05:28:12.314   Time stamp of our file: 2024-06-20 05:27:58.000
2024-06-20 05:28:12.314   Dest file exists.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.314   Time stamp of existing file: 2024-06-20 05:25:06.000
2024-06-20 05:28:12.314   Installing the file.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.351   Successfully installed the file.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.352   Saving uninstall information.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.352   Renaming uninstaller.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.352   Deleting uninstall key left over from previous administrative 64-bit install.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.353   Creating new uninstall key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{BA5DEA98-E5E3-4DC4-BB72-94005FE539FC}_is1
2024-06-20 05:28:12.353   Writing uninstall key values.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.354   Detected previous non administrative install? No
2024-06-20 05:28:12.354   Detected previous administrative 32-bit install? No
2024-06-20 05:28:12.357   Installation process succeeded.
2024-06-20 05:28:12.362   Need to restart Windows? No
2024-06-20 05:28:13.369   Deinitializing Setup.
2024-06-20 05:28:13.376   Log closed.


Your exact code works for me as expected – the file is replaced and the timestamp is updated. Please double check everything and if you still see the behaviour you are describing, we need [mcve] and the logs.

The log shows that the file was replaced. How do check the timestamp? Did you try testing file timestamp from the installer itself immediately before and after installation? You can for example use the code from https://stackoverflow.com/q/5797634/850848#41010425 and call it like beforeinstall: ShowCurrentFileTime; afterinstall: ShowCurrentFileTime with procedure ShowCurrentFileTime; begin GetModifiedFileDate(expandconstant(CurrentFileName)); end;

I look at the .EXE file I'm installing prior to compiling (which should put that date/timestamp file into the installer).  Then I check the file once the installer has run in Explorer.  The date/time do not change.  If I use another location other than "AutoTrader" (e.g., "AT") it seems to work and overwrite the date/time of the file.

So we still need the [mcve].

I thought I provided that, above, by editing my original post and including the .ISS file and the LOG.  Any .exe could be used for an example.

Can't reproduce this. I used your script and installed the file, then "back-dated" the file to 1/1/1970. Ran the installer again, and it updated the file and timestamp of the file.
