# Read modified time from one file and use it to set the time for files in a whole directory

Tags: inno-setup, last-modified

In my installer I'm extracting files from archives that don't store time/date attributes, so when they're extracted the last modified date is set to the current date. I would like to set it to the last modified date of the archive file but I can't figure out how. I tried using pieces of the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749954/get-a-files-last-updated-time-using-pascal-innosetup/1065605#1065605) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658813/how-can-i-touch-a-file-from-within-an-innosetup-script) but while it didn't give any errors, it didn't work for changing the time. Last modified date would need to be changed for * .* in a folder.

<strike>Also, where do I need to hook into to delete these files if the user cancels setup and it starts rolling back changes? I've got it taken care of in UninstallDelete but not if the user cancels setup.</strike>

EDIT: Disregard the second part, I actually figured it out shortly after I posted here. Added my own CleanUp() to DeinitializeSetup() with a check for the uninstaller registry key.

Here is the section of code I'm trying to add it to:

```
procedure VolExtract(VWorld: String);
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
  VPath: String;
begin
  // Files are extracted to {app}\VWorld\One, {app}\VWorld\Two, etc.
  VPath := ExpandConstant('{app}\' + VWorld);
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Caption := DriveLetter + VWorld + '\one.vol';
  if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\volextract.exe'), '"' + DriveLetter + VWorld + '\one.vol" "' + VPath + '"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) and (ResultCode = 0) then
  begin
    // Yep, it executed successfully
    WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Caption := DriveLetter + VWorld + '\two.vol';
    if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\volextract.exe'), '"' + DriveLetter + VWorld + '\two.vol" "' + VPath + '"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) and (ResultCode = 0) then
    begin
      // Next
      WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Caption := DriveLetter + VWorld + '\three.vol';
      if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\volextract.exe'), '"' + DriveLetter + VWorld + '\three.vol" "' + VPath + '"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) and (ResultCode = 0) then
      begin
        // Next
        WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Caption := DriveLetter + VWorld + '\four.vol';
        Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\volextract.exe'), '"' + DriveLetter + VWorld + '\four.vol" "' + VPath + '"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
      end;
    end;
  end;
  if ResultCode <> 0 then
  begin
    // Handle Fail
    CDFound := False;
    MsgBox(CustomMessage('FileErr'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
    WizardForm.Close;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the last modified time (let's call it LastWriteTime for now) for all files from a specified directory by the LastWriteTime of a certain file, use the following code after you have your files extracted. You can follow the [`commented version`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10163139/1) of the previous version of this post, but note that I've had bugs there (mixed time parameters and unused file flag parameter), but the point remains.

Also note that this code is for ANSI version of InnoSetup. If you need to use this for Unicode version, you should define the `CreateFile` function import as `CreateFileW` instead of `CreateFileA` or use the trick suggested by [`kobik`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937125/kobik) in this [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9670505/960757).

```
[code]
const
  OPEN_EXISTING = 3;  
  FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;
  GENERIC_WRITE = $40000000;
  INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = 4294967295;

function CreateFile(lpFileName: string; dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode,
  lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes: DWORD;
  hTemplateFile: THandle): THandle; 
  external 'CreateFileA@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function CloseHandle(hObject: THandle): BOOL; 
  external 'CloseHandle@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function SetFileTime(hFile: THandle; const lpCreationTime, lpLastAccessTime, 
  lpLastWriteTime: TFileTime): BOOL; 
  external 'SetFileTime@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function FileSetTime(const AFileName: string; const ACreationTime, 
  ALastAccessTime, ALastWriteTime: TFileTime): Boolean;
var
  FileHandle: THandle;
begin
  Result := False;
  FileHandle := CreateFile(AFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  if FileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  try
    Result := SetFileTime(FileHandle, ACreationTime, ALastAccessTime, 
      ALastWriteTime);
  finally
    CloseHandle(FileHandle);
  end;
end; 

procedure ModifyLastWriteTime(const ASourceFile, ATargetFolder: string);
var
  FindRec: TFindRec;
  LastWriteTime: TFileTime;
begin
  if FindFirst(ASourceFile, FindRec) then
  begin
    LastWriteTime := FindRec.LastWriteTime;
    if FindFirst(ATargetFolder + '*.*', FindRec) then
    try
      repeat
        if (FindRec.Attributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) = 0 then
          FileSetTime(ATargetFolder + FindRec.Name, FindRec.CreationTime, 
            FindRec.LastAccessTime, LastWriteTime);
      until
        not FindNext(FindRec);
    finally
      FindClose(FindRec);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And the usage. The first parameter of the `ModifyLastWriteTime` procedure is the name of the source file from which the LastWriteTime is taken. The second parameter is the directory in what the files will get modified their LastWriteTime values by the source file (don't forget to have the trailing backslash in the target folder parameter):

```
ModifyLastWriteTime('c:\SourceFile.xxx', 'c:\TargetFolder\')
```

Comment: Perfect! I'll go try this out right now, if it works I'll go ahead and mark it as the answer. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

About the second question, you can delete the files which have been extracted in a procedure called

```
Procedure CancelButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer; Var Cancel, Confirm: Boolean);
Begin
End;
```

As explained in the chm, section *Pascal Scripting: Event Functions*

About the first question I would suggest you to use inno setup [files] section instead of extracting from an archive. You could probably extract this archive to a local folder (so from your side, before compiling, and add this local folder to the [files]. But I may misunderstand your imperative about the file modification date.

Comment: in the `CancelButtonClick` you can set the `Confirm` and `Cancel` parameters to True and you will get the confirmation `Exit setup ?` dialog after the code in this event is done. So this is not the right place because you can decline this confirmation dialog.

Comment: Yeah, that was my understanding of CancelButtonClick already. I actually managed to figure out this part shortly after I originally posted this question and hadn't gotten a chance to update it yet. I added a CleanUp() procedure to DeinitializeSetup() with a check for the uninstaller key in the registry.